# Connecting to MSSQL server using LAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, lamp, dts

I have a LAMP server (Ubuntu 12.04, Apache/2.2.22, MySQL 5.5.24, PHP 5.3.10). 
However I also want to connect to other MsSQL server on other machine using Apache & PHP 
with a credentials of:

```
Server name: HENYO-GP-TEST\HENYO_GPTEST
IP: 192.168.1.36
Username: someuser
Password: somepass
Database: somedb
```

I already installed FreeDTS using 'apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php5-sybase', then configured it by 'vim /etc/freetds/freetds.conf' then edit the bottom part like this

```
# A typical Microsoft server
[192.168.1.36]
host = 192.168.1.36
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

but upon testing using 'tsql -S 192.168.1.36 -U someuser -P somepass -D somedb', the following error occured.

```
locale is "en_PH.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset is "UTF-8"
Default database being set to FAC
Error 20009 (severity 9):
   Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
   OS error 111, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

But I know the server is on because I can ping it.

Is the connection to MSSQL server (reside on other machine) possible using LAMP?
If it is possible? What are my mistakes on the installation and configuration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pinging a server doesn't necessarily imply that a particular port is open; it may respond to ICMP requests, but there's no guarantee that a given port is open. Have you confirmed that port 1433 is open on the remote server and that there is nothing blocking traffic to that port?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Server is running on an instance named `HENYO_GPTEST` (`HENYO-GP-TEST` is the server name, and `HENYO_GPTEST` is the instance name), but you are not specifying this instance name anywhere.

I'm not familiar with FreeTDS, so I don't know *how* to specify that, but you need to specify this instance name in order to connect to the server.